# Refreshing div using ajax in a django template

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I've tried implementing solutions in couple of similar questions. But none of them worked for me. I'm new to django. I'm trying to build an app which fetches whois records.

My template file is :

```
<form action = "{% url 'whoisrec:index' %}" method = "post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name = "domain" type = "text" value = "{{domain}}" />
  <button name = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Go" />
</form>

<div id = "result">
    {{text|linebreaks}}
</div>
```

I need to refresh "result" div each time new domain is entered instead of refreshing the whole page.

The script I'm using :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'whoisrec:index' %}',
        success: function(data) {
          var html = $(data).filter('#result').html();
          $('#result').html(html);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

My view:

```
def index(request):
    try:
        domain = request.POST['domain']
        requested = True
    except:
        return render(request, 'whoisrec/index.html')
        requested = False
    w = whois.whois(domain)
    text = w.text
    context = { 'domain' : domain,
                'text'  : text,
                'flag'  : requested
              }
    return render(request, 'whoisrec/index.html',context)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$.load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it only with js, using trick, you can call new version of current page, and replace only $('#result') content. (with same way work lazy_loading) something like that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button.add-comment-button").click(function() {
            $.get(window.location.href,{},function(response){
                var new_version = $('<div></div>').append(response);
                var new_result = new_version.find('#result');
                if(new_result.length){
                    $('#result').html( new_result.html() );
                    console.log('update');
                }else{
                    console.log('something wrong');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```